# How to create list in shell using for loop

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to create a new array using for loop

```
Images="alpine ubuntu centos"


Image_tags="$(for i in $Images; do
r_madoori1/$i
done)"


echo $Image_tags
```

I am expecting

```
Image_tags="r_madoori1/alpine r_madoori1/ubuntu r_madoori1/centos"
```

instead i am getting below error

```
./shell.sh: line 7: r_madoori1/alpine: No such file or directory
./shell.sh: line 7: r_madoori1/ubuntu: No such file or directory
./shell.sh: line 7: r_madoori1/centos: No such file or directory
```

Comment: _Arrays_ are a ksh/bash/zsh/etc feature not available in `sh`. But `string="item1 item2 item3"` isn't an array at all (that would be `array=( item1 item2 item3 )`), so it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @Rajeshwerwer : From the error message, it seems to me that your script is not run by _bash_. Please output `echo $BASH_VERSION` to check this. Also, you don't have any array in your code, and in the title of your question speaks of a _list_, not an array. Please be clear in what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Rajeshwerwer : Thags _bash_ and _sh_ contradict each other. Please remove one of them, and make up your mind, which shell you want to use.

Comment: You just forgot to add a `printf '%s '` in front of `r_madoori1/$i`.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop repeats commands; it's doesn't build a list of values. You could write something like

```
# OK
Image_tags="$(for i in $Images; do
 echo -n "r_madoori1/$i "
done)"
```

but it would be simpler to perform multiple assignments from the, rather than embed a loop in a single assignment.

```
# Better
for i in $Images; do
  Image_tags="$Image_tags r_madoori1/$i"
done
```

If you are using `bash`, though, you should use real arrays, not space-separated strings.

```
# Best
Images=(alpine ubuntu centos)
for i in "${Images[@]}"; do
  Image_tags+=( "r_maddori1/$i" )
done
```

or more concisely

```
Images=(alpine ubuntu centos)
Image_tags=("${Images[@]/#/r_madoori1/}")
```

Comment: But it is only printing 1st element in array 
r_maddori1/alpine
r_maddori1/alpine
r_maddori1/alpine

i am expecting 

r_maddori1/alpine
r_maddori1/ubuntu
r_maddori1/centos

Comment: Did you mistype something? I can't reproduce that.

Comment: Images=(alpine ubuntu centos)
for i in $Images; do
  Image_tags="$Image_tags r_madoori1/$i"
  echo $Image_tags
done

I tried this

Comment: `Images=(...)` and `Images="..."` are two different values. You aren't using the real array properly. Please look at the third example carefully.

Comment: If it's bash, no need for loop : `Image_tags=(${Images[@]/#/r_madoori1/})`

Comment: @Philippe, need more quotes to prevent string-splitting in that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed, this should be fine : `Image_tags=("${Images[@]/#/r_madoori1/}")`

Answer (score 2):

Without using any loop you can do this in `bash`:

```sh
Images="alpine ubuntu centos"

Image_tags="r_madoori1/${Images// / r_madoori1\/}"

echo "$Image_tags"
```

**Output:**

```
r_madoori1/alpine r_madoori1/ubuntu r_madoori1/centos
```

Comment: This is bash-only, correct? Might want to make that explicit since this is also tagged `sh`.

Comment: Thanks, I have added it now. Didn't notice `sh` tag earlier.